# Не могу понять почему не могу найти страницу

Tags: yii2

вот контролер
\frontend\controllers\СabinetController.php

в контролере сознад такой класс class CabinetController extends Controller
и есть такой экшен

```
public function actionIndex($id)
    {
        $productsQuery = OrderItem::find();
        if ($id !== null && isset($categories[$id])) {
            $productsQuery->where(['userid' =>  $id]);
        }
        $productsDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $productsQuery,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10,
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('index', [
            'productsDataProvider' => $productsDataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

вот вид здесь
\frontend\views\cabinet\index.php

в адресе набираю так frontend/web/cabinet/index?id=1 вываливается ошибка 404 подскажите где туплю

Comment: А какие неймспейсы в контроллере подключены? а `htaccess` никакие не используете для перенаправления? Например для входа на главную страницу фронтенда вы что набираете? `mysite.ru/fronend/web/` или просто `mysite.ru` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский namespace frontend\controllers; это неймспейс другие страницы открываются по ссылке mysite.ru/fronend/web/site/index и да htaccess импользую вот к примеру рабочая ссылка frontend/web/catalog/list?id=3

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский namespace frontend\controllers; это неймспейс другие страницы открываются по ссылке mysite.ru/fronend/web/site/index и да htaccess импользую вот к примеру рабочая ссылка frontend/web/catalog/list?id=3

Comment: в `urlManager` есть правила? может они что перезаписывают?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот весь конфиг
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    /*'defaultRoute'=>'catalog/list',*/
    'components' => [
            'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',

Comment: 'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'cart' => [
            'class' => 'yz\shoppingcart\ShoppingCart',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];